# JFrog Artifactory HA cluster configuration

Tags: cluster-computing, artifactory, high-availability

Im configuring 2 Artifactory servers (WinServer OS).

following the configuration its all nice and dandy, but the issue is regarding filestore.
Filestore is where each ART server keep its Packages (Nugets,NPM,JAR etc..).

The basic configuration for single server is:

```
<config version="1">
    <chain template="file-system"/>
</config>
```

Cluster configuration, according to Gudielines is:

```
<config version="2">
    <chain template="cluster-file-system"/>
</config>
```

Which supposingly gives me redundancy, if one server is down.
But while taking down NODE1 (which formly was the main single Artifactory server), i do get NODE2 to operate and resolvance is good.

Yet while running build that consumes artifactory i get "Internal server error 500".
While looking into the error closely, it claims that some package is not found on NODE2.

I've checked the local "data\filestore" there is nothing, while on NODE1, it contains many packages.

TY guys !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after having a discussion with JFrog support.
It seems that in order to have Node1 and Node2 replicating FILESTORE (where all packages reside). a flag should be raised.

This can be done by invoking a POST command:

**curl -u username:password -X POST "https://servername:8443/artifactory/api/system/storage/optimize"**

After that, and this is the most important thing, Garbage collection must be invoked 20 times (its the Default), in order to start the synching.
Therefore, we have to run this command 20 times:

**curl -u username:password -X POST "https://servername:8443/artifactory/api/system/storage/gc"**

Alternatively, there is a configuration that can override this default.
go to your Artifactory server, $artifactory_home/etc/artifactory.system.property
and modify this file to have this line: ***artifactory.gc.skipFullGcBetweenMonitorIterations=1***

This should be aplied to all Nodes
Service restart is a must on all nodes in the cluster

After that Synch between Nodes will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory HA? The configurations must match. My config binarystore.xml:

```
<config version="2">
    <chain template="cluster-file-system"/>
</config>
```

Load balancing is carried out by the nginx or other reverse proxy. More: System Architecture - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/System+Architecture

Comment: Thanks for sharing the config.

My first configuration was exactly the same, yet when NODE1 was offline ive got error that the requested paclage is not available...
Weird stuff

Comment: All files are stored on the master node. On the second note, they may not be. The cluster stores all files like this: n (node) -1.

Comment: How will i have redundancy then?
Isnt HA cluster suppose to solve single point of failure ?
if Node1 has all the binaries, then when its down, Node2 will not function also....

TBH im confused...

Comment: >>> How will i have redundancy then?
3 node, 5 node, 7 node...
We used 3 node.

Comment: You say the minimum for a cluster is 3 nodes?
I assumed,since there is no minimum required for cluster, that 2 Nodes (Primary and Member) would be enough for a cluster.

So basically according to the logic of cluster file storing, n (node) -1, my secondary Node will never have replica of all packages, thus creating a single point of failure.

I hope i am missing something, as this seems to be not a reliable solution for a cluster behaviour.

Cheers